# How can I migrate Rails passwords to Laravel?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am migrating a Rails app to Laravel, and all that is missing now is using being able to use the old password data from Rails in Laravel.

I plan on saving the old information on a new separate column and when the user logins, compare the password with the information I got from the old Rails database, and if correct, save the password with Laravel hashing methods.

What I would like to know is how can I check, using PHP, that the password the user submitted is the correct one from the old Rails app?

Comment: is the "rails password' hashed or plain text?

Comment: Hashed, that is the thing, if it was plain text I would hash it with Laravel directly. But I need to compare the user submitted password with the hash I got from Rails.

Comment: do you know how its hashed?

Comment: Nop, I know it was a Rails app, but I do not have access to the code, I don't know if there is a standard Rails hashing.

Comment: your most likely out of luck, the point of hashing is to stop the reversal you want

Comment: If you do not have access of code then probably you are making site from others site not your?

Comment: I saw a post on pretty much exactly this question earlier this week. It basically said `bcrypt(base64(RUBY_ALGORITHM($password)))`. Let me try and find that post again. EDIT: doesn't completely answer your question, but if you can figure out the Ruby hash algorithm, this might be of use: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183358/how-secure-is-bcryptsha1password

Comment: @C2486, yes, not mine, I was hired to develop the Laravel version/

Comment: @Loek, thanks for the link, pointed me in the right direction. The answer was in front of me, but did not see it at first. Nothing needs to be done, both encrypt with Bcrypt.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out both use the same hashing system by default (bcrypt) so, nothing needs to be done if you have not modified the core password management of the frameworks.

Just migrate the old password data to the new database and it should be compatible.